# draw lines overlayed to picture in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, overlay, paint

I am trying to replicate this control in vb.net, but with HSL values instead of HSV.
So far I figured out that all are image boxes, including the sliders. The Image of the color wheel is 180x128 (half the complete color range, that is 360x255) The position of the imageboxes defines the selected color range.

[image]

When you move the sliders, those lines are painted on the image, but they are overlayed. they are not on the image itself. and they move with the slider position.

How can these lines be drawn overlayed to a picture, and what is the best way to move them? at each moved pixel delete and redraw the lines? isnt that slow?

----- edit-----

current code:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
    Try
        Dim gxoff As Graphics
        Dim pen As Pen = New Pen(Color.Azure)
        gxoff.DrawImage(Me.PictureBox1.Image, New Rectangle(Me.PictureBox1.Left, Me.PictureBox1.Top, Me.PictureBox1.Width, Me.PictureBox1.Height), New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.PictureBox1.Image.Width, Me.PictureBox1.Image.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Dash
        Dim num1 As Integer = Math.Min(Me.PictureBox1.Width - 1, Math.Max(0, Me.Hmax.Left - Me.PictureBox1.Left + 7)) + Me.PictureBox1.Left
        Dim num2 As Integer = Math.Min(Me.PictureBox1.Width - 1, Math.Max(0, Me.Hmin.Left - Me.PictureBox1.Left + 7)) + Me.PictureBox1.Left
        Dim num3 As Integer = Math.Min(Me.PictureBox1.Height - 1, Math.Max(0, Me.Smax.Top - Me.PictureBox1.Top + Me.Smax.Height)) + Me.PictureBox1.Top
        Dim num4 As Integer = Math.Min(Me.PictureBox1.Height - 1, Math.Max(0, Me.Smin.Top - Me.PictureBox1.Top)) + Me.PictureBox1.Top
        gxoff.DrawLine(pen, Me.PictureBox1.Left, num3, Me.PictureBox1.Left + Me.PictureBox1.Width, num3)
        gxoff.DrawLine(pen, Me.PictureBox1.Left, num4, Me.PictureBox1.Left + Me.PictureBox1.Width, num4)
        gxoff.DrawLine(pen, num1, Me.PictureBox1.Top, num1, Me.PictureBox1.Height + Me.PictureBox1.Top)
        gxoff.DrawLine(pen, num2, Me.PictureBox1.Top, num2, Me.PictureBox1.Height + Me.PictureBox1.Top)
        pen.DashStyle = DashStyle.Solid
        pen.Width = 2.0F
        gxoff.DrawLine(pen, num1, num3, num1, num4)
        gxoff.DrawLine(pen, num2, num3, num2, num4)

        If Me.Hmin.Left < Me.Hmax.Left Then
            gxoff.DrawLine(pen, num1, num3, num2, num3)
            gxoff.DrawLine(pen, num1, num4, num2, num4)
        Else
            gxoff.DrawLine(pen, Me.PictureBox1.Left, num3, num1, num3)
            gxoff.DrawLine(pen, Me.PictureBox1.Left, num4, num1, num4)
            gxoff.DrawLine(pen, num2, num3, Me.PictureBox1.Width + Me.PictureBox1.Left, num3)
            gxoff.DrawLine(pen, num2, num4, Me.PictureBox1.Width + Me.PictureBox1.Left, num4)
        End If



    Catch
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Handle the `Paint` event of the `PictureBox` you want draw the lines over.

Comment: Thanks, but wont that paint on the image directly? I would like to paint on top of it, so that the lines can be moved.. like a layer in photoshop for instance..

Comment: What happened when you tested it for yourself?

Comment: it doesnt paint anything at all... just updated the post with the current code..

Comment: Never write Try/Catch-em-all-do-nothing code.  Fix the bug with gxoff = e.Graphics.  Don't use DrawImage(), PictureBox already takes care of that.

Comment: Thanks! now it draws a rectangle (in the wrong position, but that is something i have to figure out) and remains there.. it does not update..

Comment: And did it draw on the `Image`?  If you display the same `Image` in another `PictureBox` does it have the lines on it?  If the answer is "no" then you know that this is the correct option and you can then do some research on the subject and learn how to do it properly.

Comment: @jmcilhinney nope, its not drawing on the other image.. but i am a bit lost on this.. the paint event is called when i open the form, and then never again.. so if I move my sliders, the original rectangle remainst where it was.. is there a proper way to cause a redrawing of the image?

Comment: calling picturebox1.refresh() did the trick.. :) thank you all

Comment: Your `PaintEventArgs` e will contain a `graphics` object already, so you don't need to create one. just get the one from the event and continue creating graphics on that, this way you won't need to draw the picture yourself because it will already be on the graphics object when you get it.